# issues in accessing contacts in android marshmallow

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

i am getting errors while accessing contacts from the phone in my application.
i have added access permission for android marshmallow . when i accept the permission the application crashes. and i am not sure about the permission  code i have used...can some one tell me  where i am going wrong..here is the code..

```
 public class ContactsDisplay extends AppCompatActivity implements  OnItemClickListener,FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

        private static String TAG = ContactsDisplay.class.getSimpleName();

        private Toolbar mToolbar;
        private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;

        Cursor phones;

        List<String> name1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> phno1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        MyAdapter ma ;
        Button select;

        private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 1;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            //getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            setContentView(R.layout.contacts_display);
            mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView10);
            setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

            drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
                    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
            drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
            drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);

            // display the second navigation drawer view on app launch
            displayView(0);

            getAllContacts(this.getContentResolver());
            ListView lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
            ma = new MyAdapter();
            lv.setAdapter(ma);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
            lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
            lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
            // adding
            select = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

            select.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    StringBuilder checkedcontacts= new StringBuilder();
                    System.out.println(".............."+ma.mCheckStates.size());
                    for(int i = 0; i < name1.size(); i++)

                    {
                        if(ma.mCheckStates.get(i)==true)
                        {
                            checkedcontacts.append(name1.get(i).toString());
                            checkedcontacts.append("\n");

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Not Checked......"+name1.get(i).toString());
                        }


                    }

                    Toast.makeText(ContactsDisplay.this, checkedcontacts,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {

                ma.toggle(position);
            }




        public  void getAllContacts(ContentResolver cr) {

            int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ContactsDisplay.this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);
            if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

                phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
                contactsdisplay();

            } else {

                requestForLocationPermission();
            }
        }

        private void requestForLocationPermission()
        {

            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(ContactsDisplay.this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS))
            {
            }
            else {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ContactsDisplay.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults)
        {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS:
                    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    {
  getAllContacts(ContactsDisplay.this.getContentResolver());                        
contactsdisplay();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        public  void contactsdisplay() {

            phones.moveToFirst();
        do
        {
            String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            System.out.println(".................."+phoneNumber);
            name1.add(name);
            phno1.add(phoneNumber);
        }while (phones.moveToNext());
        }

        class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener
        {  private SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
            LayoutInflater mInflater;
            TextView tv1,tv;
            CheckBox cb;
            MyAdapter()
            {
                mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(name1.size());
                mInflater = (LayoutInflater)ContactsDisplay.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            }
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return name1.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return position;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                View vi=convertView;
                if(convertView==null)
                    vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
                TextView tv= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                tv1= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                cb = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_id);
                tv.setText("Name :"+ name1.get(position));
                tv1.setText("Phone No :"+ phno1.get(position));
                cb.setTag(position);
                cb.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, false));
                cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

                return vi;
            }
            public boolean isChecked(int position) {
                return mCheckStates.get(position, false);
            }

            public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
                mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);
                System.out.println("hello...........");
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            public void toggle(int position) {
                setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));
            }
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                         boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);
            }
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            if(id == R.id.action_search){
                 /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), vault_no, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;*/
                logout();
            }

            if(id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        private void logout(){
            //Creating an alert dialog to confirm logout
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to logout?");
            alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                            //Getting out sharedpreferences
                            SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(ClickToLogin.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                            //Getting editor
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

                            //Puting the value false for loggedin
                            editor.putBoolean(ClickToLogin.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, false);

                            //Putting blank value to email
                            editor.putString(ProfileLogin.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF, "");
                            editor.putString(ClickToLogin.FULLNAME_SHARED_PREF,  "");
                            editor.putString(ClickToLogin.MOBILE_SHARED_PREF, "");
                            editor.putString(ClickToLogin.POB_SHARED_PREF,  "");
                            editor.putString(ClickToLogin.DOB_SHARED_PREF,  "");
                            editor.putString(ClickToLogin.PIN_SHARED_PREF, "");
                            editor.putString(ClickToLogin.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF,  "");
                            editor.putString(ClickToLogin.DOC_SHARED_PREF, "");
                            editor.putString(ClickToLogin.YEAR_SHARED_PREF, "");
                            editor.clear();
                            //Saving the sharedpreferences
                            editor.commit();

                            //Starting login activity
                            Intent intent = new Intent(ContactsDisplay.this, ProfileLogin.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });

            alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                        }
                    });

            //Showing the alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
            displayView(position);
        }

        private void displayView(int position) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    /*fragment = new HomeFragment();*/
                    title = "Work Details1";

                    break;

                case 1:
                    /*fragment = new ProfileFragment();
                    title = getString(R.string.title_profile);
                    break;*/
                    startActivity(new Intent(this, ContactsDisplay.class));
                    return;
                case 2:

                    startActivity(new Intent (this,Events.class));
                    return;
                    /*fragment = new AboutFragment();
                    title = getString(R.string.title_about);
                    break;*/
                case 3:
                    fragment = new MessagesFragment();
                    title = getString(R.string.title_messages);
                    break;

                case 4:
                    fragment = new VideoFragment();
                    title = getString(R.string.title_video);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    fragment = new GalleryFragment();
                    title = getString(R.string.title_gallery);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    fragment = new GalleryFragment();
                    title = "Gallery";
                    break;

                case 7:
                    fragment = new EventsFragment();
                    title = getString(R.string.title_events);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }

            if (fragment != null) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

                // set the toolbar title
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {

            finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(ContactsDisplay.this, DocUpload.class);

            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    }
```

here is the logcat

```
06-13 05:37:22.000 11581-11581/com.example.miisky E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                          Process: com.example.miisky, PID: 11581
                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.miisky/com.example.miisky.ContactsDisplay}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.database.Cursor.moveToNext()' on a null object reference
                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3699)
                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.database.Cursor.moveToNext()' on a null object reference
                                                          at com.example.miisky.ContactsDisplay.contactsdisplay(ContactsDisplay.java:199)
                                                          at com.example.miisky.ContactsDisplay.onRequestPermissionsResult(ContactsDisplay.java:190)
                                                          at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:6553)
                                                          at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6432)
                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3695)
                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742) 
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393) 
                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with my code was AppcompatActivity..i changed AppcompatActivity to Actitvity..Now the Code runs fine ..Even the access permission for marshmallow is asked while accessing contacts..

So this is the final code..

```
public class DisplayContact extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{

    //ArrayList to store name and phone number
    List<String> name1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> phno1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    MyAdapter ma ;
    Button select;
    Cursor phones;

    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        setContentView(R.layout.display);


        getAllContacts(this.getContentResolver());
        ListView lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        ma = new MyAdapter();
        lv.setAdapter(ma);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        // adding
        select = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        select.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                StringBuilder checkedcontacts= new StringBuilder();

                for(int i = 0; i < name1.size(); i++)

                {
                    if(ma.mCheckStates.get(i)==true)
                    {
                        checkedcontacts.append(name1.get(i).toString());
                        checkedcontacts.append(phno1.get(i).toString());
                        checkedcontacts.append("\n");

                    else
                    {

                    }
                }
               Toast.makeText(DisplayContact.this, checkedcontacts, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ma.toggle(arg2);
    }

    public  void getAllContacts(ContentResolver cr) {

        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(DisplayContact.this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
            contactsdisplay();

        } else {

            requestForLocationPermission();
        }
    }

    private void requestForLocationPermission()
    {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(DisplayContact.this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS))
        {
        }
        else {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(DisplayContact.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults)
    {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    getAllContacts(DisplayContact.this.getContentResolver());
                    contactsdisplay();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    public  void contactsdisplay() {

        //Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
        while (phones.moveToNext())
        {
            String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            System.out.println(".................."+name+ "" +phoneNumber);
            name1.add(name);
            phno1.add(phoneNumber);
        }

        phones.close();
    }

    class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener
    {  private SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
        LayoutInflater mInflater;
        TextView tv1,tv;
        CheckBox cb;
        MyAdapter()
        {
            mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(name1.size());
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater)DisplayContact.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return name1.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View vi=convertView;
            if(convertView==null)
                vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            tv= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
            tv1= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.phone_number);
            cb = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_id);
            tv.setText("Name :"+ name1.get(position));
            tv1.setText("Phone No :"+ phno1.get(position));
            cb.setTag(position);
            cb.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, false));
            cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

            return vi;
        }
        public boolean isChecked(int position) {
            return mCheckStates.get(position, false);
        }

        public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
            mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);
        }

        public void toggle(int position) {
            setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));
        }
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                     boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        finish();
        Intent intent = new Intent(DisplayContact.this, ProfileDisplay.class);

        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling getAllContacts() in which you have checked for the required permission and if permission is already granted you are getting the list of contacts. Issue with your code is when you do not have permission, you are asking for it. So now when user allow or deny, you again required to call same method getAllContacts() also from onRequestPermissionsResult(). Currently it is happening that user Allowed but you have yet not fetched the contact and going directly to read it.

Add your getAllContacts() call also inside onRequestPermissionsResult() i.e.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults){
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                     getAllContacts(ContactsDisplay.this.getContentResolver());
                    contactsdisplay();
                }else{
                   //Show a dialog with explanation why you want contacts permission and ask for permission again or else simply display appropriate error or alert message.
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

So to explain firstly when you call getAllContacts() and you already have permission granted your Cursor phones will have values. But if you do not have permission, so you display an dialog requesting permission and when user allow you are directly calling contactsdisplay() which is wrong. You have to first getAllContacts() as user just granted you permission and then call contactsdisplay().

Comment: i have changed according to ur code..it is not asking for permission..just displaying blank page..

Comment: no it was not displaying.. now the error has gone..but i am not getting permission dialog ..what might be the problem,,?

Comment: Sorry but you need to call getAllContacts(this.getContentResolver()); in onCreate as well, as you did earlier. So your flow will be complete and you will be displayed with permission dialog. So your getAllContacts() method will be called from both onCreate() as well as from onRequestPermissionsResult() as i mentioned in my answer.

Comment: check the modification.

Comment: i have made some modifications to contactsdisplay method in the above code...but i am getting print statement with phone number..but nothing is displayed in actual device..

Comment: which  print statement?

Comment: it seems issue with your adapter is not calling getview() method for rendering the listview. I think you require to call notifyDataSetChanged() on your adapter instance after your name1 and phone1 list are  populated with required data. Pl google for baseadapter implementation example.